# Bootstrap - Nav list items are stacking on top of each other at 992px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I'm trying to do a nav-bar like a windows/macos -- ish taskbar, and I got an issue.
At `992px`, the list items are stacking on top of each other, and can't see why.

What I want to obtain, is, having a "navbar" that keeps the same width when I shrink the window. The first problem I ran into, was, making the width of the bar smaller, which I solved by adding:

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar {
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 40%;
}
```

to  `@media (min-width:1200px)`.

After that, when the screen reaches `1200px` the bar is resizing to its default width (100%), then, at `992px`, it just brokes out.

(To mention: I don't have a lot of experience with "responsiveness" but I know how to use bootstrap, and using the latest version!)

Here is my `bootstrap.min.css` content, and `index.html`.

**html**: https://pastebin.com/fTUmYVYt

**css**: https://pastebin.com/JXZsG0Nm

Also, I added a video to youtube, where you can see the problem more "clearly"
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYaBzFrSdwI)

Comment: Strange, the HTML looks OK to me but I think you have posted the entirity of Bootstrap's CSS. Have you edited any of that CSS that is to do with the nav?

Comment: I am not currently at home, but something that I edited about navbar was about placing it down (bottom 0) instead of top. Also, I added the blur, shadow and the margin that i mentioned before.